# How to remove apostrophe/byte marks from string sentences when trying to parse yaml

Tags: go, parsing, yaml

Live example [here](https://go.dev/play/p/uh7XbxDWe-7)

It seems like the yaml parsing library is unable to print `"`
So when i parse a sentence with `"`, go adds byte apostrophe around it (`'`)

Is there some trick to just have it print/make simple string/quotation string, without the byte apostrophes added?

Example code:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    yaml "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

type X struct {
    Example string `yaml:"some-example"`
}

func main() {
    item := X{
        Example: fmt.Sprint("\"some text\""),
    }

    res, err := yaml.Marshal(item)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Print(string(res))
}
```

Prints `some-example: '"some text"'`

Want `some-example: "some text"`

Comment: The yaml package is doing exactly what you are telling it to, you want to marshal the string, which contains quotes, so they must be escaped somehow. If you don't want the quotes, remove them from the string in the first place. You asked how to do this when parsing yaml, but the example is marshaling the value, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: what about doing a replace? `strings.Replace(string(res), "\"", "", -1)`

Comment: Hello @JimB. As the last sentence in the question says, i want to print out: some-example: "some text" , not some-example: '"some text"'.  I hope this makes it clearer when pointing out what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some trick to just have it print/make simple string/quotation string, without the byte apostrophes added?

Note that you are printing the output of `yaml.Marshal`, i.e. you are printing a valid YAML document and YAML does not have anything called "byte apostrophes". In YAML strings can be either [unquoted](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#plain-style), [double quoted](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#double-quoted-style), or [**single quoted**](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#single-quoted-style), regardless, they are all strings.

```yaml
# all three are strings 
a: foo bar
b: "foo bar"
c: 'foo bar'
```

So your original output

```yaml
some-example: '"some text"'
```

is perfectly valid YAML, and it is not Go that is adding the single quotes, it is the [`gopkg.in/yaml.v3`](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v3) package that's doing that.

---

AFAICT it is not possible to set a global setting for the [`yaml.Encoder`](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v3#Encoder) to marshal every string using the double-quoted style, however you can use a custom string that implements [`yaml.Marshaler`](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v3#Marshaler) to force the `yaml.Encoder` to always output double quoted strings for any value of that custom type.

For example:

```golang
type DoubleQuotedString string

func (s DoubleQuotedString) MarshalYAML() (interface{}, error) {
    return yaml.Node{
        Kind:  yaml.ScalarNode,
        Style: yaml.DoubleQuotedStyle, // <- this is the relevant part
        Value: string(s),
    }, nil
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/o9VNL5mKdSl

```yaml
some-example: "\"some text\""
```

Comment: This code hurts my brain, so i guess there is more to learn from my side. Very nice, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, Printing out the field of struct with %+v does not show single quotes but somehow during the marshaling process using the gopkg.in/yaml.v3 package, single quote is being added. As a result my yaml(apparently, even though is valid) looks odd

```
  k8s_labels:
  - '"nic-type-sriov=false"'
```